# Kurento: No remote video feed when running "one2one-call" between peers on different networks

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I have successfully run the "one2one-call" Kurento tutorial using a Windows KMS server, but am unable to see remote video when one of the peers is on a different network.

I have two laptops (one for each peer). One of these laptops is also running the Windows KMS server and the Application server. 
I have also enabled port forwarding so that both peers can navigate to the web browser using the public IP and port number.

This works when both laptops are connected to the same network; but when I connect one of the laptops to another network, the remote video is no longer displayed. I can view the UI, register and attempt a call, additionally, when attempting the call, a notification does pop up on the remote peer and both peers get the popup requesting permission to access the microphone and camera, but no remote video. Each peer is only able to see their own image.

Would appreciate any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure STUN and TURN in KMS config file? (WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini)

Try adding STUN server to config file. You can use google's STUN server.

```
stunServerAddress=74.125.143.127
stunServerPort=19302
```

If adding STUN to config did not work, you need TURN. If either of these networks have restrictive firewalls you will need to set up TURN server and add it to KMS configuration.

```
turnURL=USER:PASS@YOUR_MACHINE_PUBLIC_IP:<PORT>
```

You will also need to modify JavaScript for browser to use TURN.

For the reference: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers

Comment: Thanks, I was using a different IP and port number for the stunServer; The one you mentioned above worked though. I tested this tutorial to have a transatlantic conversation; It worked ,  the audio quality was not great. Do you know of factors that could influence this? Much Appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help. I am not sure about factors that could influence audio quality. I can only think of position of server and clients, internet bandwidth, audio codecs, background noise. I don't know if this was helpful, but you might get some idea from it.